# Can't link URL with virtual host

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I am really new to servers and apache however I've been struggling for a while now and maybe somebody can help me.

So I have set up an apache server that works (if I use the IP address I can reach the website and it works properly). I have linked the url with the nameservers and my virtual host file looks like (located in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite)

```
<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mysite1.com
    ServerName mysite1.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite1.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/mysite1.com/public_html/
    ErrorLog /srv/www/mysite1.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/www/mysite1.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The weirdest thing is it worked yesterday and in the meantime I only installed an FTP server ... Any ideas of what I might have done wrong?

Thank you

Comment: are you sure, that ping mysite1.com shows 12.34.56.78? if so, then try <VirtualHost *:80> instead of <VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>

Comment: without configure your dns right you are not able to use virtualhost with dns-names ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is on Debian, you also need to link your config file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, to let the config scripts know that the file is not only available, but also enabled.

Another thing might want to check is `NameVirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80` directive somewhere in Apache config (or, optionally `NameVirtualHost *:80`).

Comment: When you run `apache2 -S`, does the dump include your vhost?